# lstlisting: how to underline a keyword?

Tags: listings

In the following, I am trying to underline the keyword 'true' in a C++ code listing.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern} % bold and italic ttfamily
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    moredelim=**[is][\underbar]{@}{@}     % <----
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    int i = foo(@true@);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

What I get is:

[image]

If I use `[is]` instead of `**[is]`, the word 'true' is underlined,
but in this case it is not highlighted as a keyword.

How can I underline a keyword, without loosing its highlighting?

**Update 1:**

At the same time, I would like to underline words that are not keywords.
For example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
    int @i@ = foo(@true@);
\end{lstlisting}
```

**Update 2:**

Using `\slshape` instead of `\underbar` generates the expected output.

[image]

Why does `\slshape` work and `\underbar` does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a workaround in which you should patch `\lst@DelimClose` and add `\underbar` within the command

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern} % bold and italic ttfamily
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter

\def\lst@DelimClose#1#2#3\@empty{%
    \lst@TrackNewLines \underbar{\lst@XPrintToken}\relax
    \lst@DelimPrint{#1#2}{#3}%
    \lst@LeaveMode
    \lst@DelimPrint{#1}{#3}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    keepspaces=true,
    moredelim=**[is]{@}{@},    
    }


\begin{lstlisting}
    int i = foo(@true@);
    @hello@, @and@
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[is]` and replace `\underbar` with `\color{blue}\bfseries\underbar`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern} % bold and italic ttfamily
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    moredelim=[is][\color{blue}\bfseries\underbar]{@}{@}    
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    int i = foo(@true@);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

---

**Update**

If you have a list of `keywords` you can create another `moredelim` with another character.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern} % bold and italic ttfamily
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}




\lstset{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    moredelim=[is][\color{blue}\bfseries\underbar]{@}{@},    
    moredelim=[is][\underbar]{(*}{*)}
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    int i = foo(@true@);
    (*hello*)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry, I forgot to mention that I would like also to underline words that are not keywords. Please see the update.

Comment: @sergej Changing the question like that after receiving a nice answer for the original problem doesn't seem fair, does it?. Even the title of your question refers only to keywords. Next time, please, state your goal clearly from the beginning to avoid waste of time.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer! However, I would prefer a solution with only one `moredelim` definition, I don't want to think about whether a word is a keyword or not, the `lstlisting` package knows that.